# Selecionar colunas em arquivo .txt no python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Eu tenho um arquivo .txt com a seguinte informação

```
    no        id   name            status     mothers   daughters     colours      p_x        p_y        p_z         e          m 
     0        90   (system)           -11     0     0     0     0     0     0      0.000      0.000      0.000  13000.000  13000.000
     1      2212   (p+)               -12     0     0   290     0     0     0      0.000      0.000   6500.000   6500.000      0.938
     2      2212   (p+)               -12     0     0   291     0     0     0      0.000      0.000  -6500.000   6500.000      0.938
     3        21   (g)                -21     8     0     5     7   504   501      0.000      0.000    274.941    274.941      0.000
     4        21   (g)                -21     9     9     5     7   503   502     -0.000     -0.000   -863.279    863.279      0.000
     5   1000021   (~g)               -22     3     4    10    10   503   505     55.235    -21.966   -704.106    749.532    250.000
     6   1000021   (~g)               -22     3     4    11    11   504   502    -76.457     61.717      4.513    268.654    250.000
     7        21   (g)                -23     3     4    12    12   505   501     21.222    -39.751    111.255    120.034      0.000
     8        21   (g)                -41    14    14    13     3   504   506     -0.000     -0.000    850.624    850.624      0.000
     9        21   (g)                -42    15     0     4     4   503   502      0.000     -0.000   -863.279    863.279      0.000
    10   1000021   (~g)               -44     5     5    16    16   503   505     50.140    -14.547   -681.656    727.929    250.000
    11   1000021   (~g)               -44     6     6    17    17   504   502   -107.092    106.334    -14.102    292.360    250.000
    12        21   (g)                -44     7     7    18    18   505   501     -4.716     -1.973    117.744    117.855      0.000
    13        21   (g)                -43     8     0    19    19   501   506     61.667    -89.814    565.357    575.759      0.000
    14        21   (g)                -42    21     0     8     8   504   506      0.000     -0.000    850.624    850.624      0.000
    15        21   (g)                -41    22    22    20     9   507   502     -0.000      0.000  -1732.121   1732.121      0.000
    16   1000021   (~g)               -44    10    10    23    23   503   505     33.157     41.436   -684.169    730.345    250.000
    17   1000021   (~g)               -44    11    11    24    24   504   502   -110.784    118.505     -9.365    298.168    250.000
    18        21   (g)                -44    12    12    25    25   505   501     -4.717     -1.969    117.312    117.424      0.000
    19        21   (g)                -44    13    13    26    26   501   506     61.542    -89.401    559.065    569.503      0.000
    20        21   (g)                -43    15     0    27    27   507   503     20.802    -68.571   -864.340    867.305      0.000
    21        -4   (cbar)             -41    35    35    28    14     0   506      0.000      0.000   1958.533   1958.533      0.000
    22        21   (g)                -42    36     0    15    15   507   502     -0.000     -0.000  -1732.121   1732.121      0.000
    23   1000021   (~g)               -44    16    16    37    37   503   505     32.678     41.029   -683.347    729.530    250.000
    24   1000021   (~g)               -44    17    17    31    31   504   502   -113.785    115.964     -9.452    298.302    250.000
    25        21   (g)                -44    18    18    39    39   505   501     -7.156     -4.034    117.243    117.531      0.000
    26        21   (g)                -44    19    19    40    40   501   506     49.817    -99.331    558.905    569.845      0.000
    27        21   (g)                -44    20    20    41    41   507   503     20.771    -68.597   -864.587    867.553      0.000
    28        -4   (cbar)             -43    21     0    29    30     0   504     17.674     14.969   1107.650   1107.893      1.500
    29        -4   (cbar)             -51    28     0    34    34     0   508      3.345     31.184   1021.946   1022.428      1.500
    30        21   (g)                -51    28     0    32    33   508   504     13.322    -15.242     83.870     86.278      0.000
```

Eu preciso separar todas as colunas desse arquivo.
Eu não consigo abrir apenas com `pandas.read_csv('arquivo.txt')` porque dessa maneira aparece apenas uma única coluna e eu gostaria de deixar o DataFrame no formato usual com as colunas `no        id   name            status     mothers   daughters     colours      p_x        p_y        p_z         e          m`

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) do `pandas` você pode usar uma das formas abaixo

```
pandas.read_csv('arquivo.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

ou

```
pandas.read_csv('arquivo.txt', sep='\s+')
```

ou

```
pandas.read_csv('arquivo.txt', delimiter='\s+')
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Consegui resolver